# White icon disappeared after second click on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

This is how my code works:

1. when click the icon, the dropdown content will fade in
2. when click again, the dropdown content will fade out

My code is working well on desktop but don't know why there is a problem on mobile. The icon disappeared after second click.

1. Look good on mobile
   [image]
2. Click and shows the content
   [image]
3. Click again to close, but the icon disappeared
   [image]

Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".advanced_search a").click(function(){
        $(".overlay_search").fadeToggle(200);
  
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('advancedsearch_icon_active')) {
   $(".advanced_search a").removeClass('advancedsearch_icon_active').addClass('advancedsearch_icon');
  } else if ($this.hasClass('advancedsearch_icon')) {
   $(".advanced_search a").removeClass('advancedsearch_icon').addClass('advancedsearch_icon_active');
  } else {
   $(".advanced_search a").addClass("advancedsearch_icon");
  }
    });
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.advancedsearch_icon{
 background: url('https://image.ibb.co/fxUXFQ/filter.png') no-repeat right 0; width: 20px; height: 20px; padding-left: 20px;
}
.advancedsearch_icon:hover, .advancedsearch_icon_active{
 background: url('https://image.ibb.co/kY4opk/filter_hover.png') no-repeat right 0; width: 20px; height: 20px; padding-left: 20px;
}

.overlay_search {
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 background:#eeeeee;
 overflow:hidden;
 z-index:3;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 24px -8px rgba(18,17,12,0.5); -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 24px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); box-shadow: 7px 7px 24px -8px rgba(18,17,12,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="advanced_search">
  <a class="advancedsearch_icon" href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="overlay_search">
  content is here.
</div>
```

Comment: keep in mind that on mobile devices there is no `:hover` event.  you can use `:active` but use it AFTER `:hover` . Example `a:hover, a:active { styles } ` .  Maybe this is causing the problem

Comment: Cool! Why I never think about that. Keep focusing on jqeury. Thought I do something wrong. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Glad i could help! :D I'll post it as an answer so other user looking for solution will see it better

Comment: sure! I will mark this as answer, but my question is so lame. Didn't notice about the small problem like this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that on mobile devices there is no `:hover` event. You can use `:active` but use it AFTER `:hover` . Example `a:hover, a:active { styles }` . Maybe this is causing the problem

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".advanced_search a").click(function(){
        $(".overlay_search").fadeToggle(200);
  
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('advancedsearch_icon_active')) {
   $(".advanced_search a").removeClass('advancedsearch_icon_active').addClass('advancedsearch_icon');
  } else if ($this.hasClass('advancedsearch_icon')) {
   $(".advanced_search a").removeClass('advancedsearch_icon').addClass('advancedsearch_icon_active');
  } else {
   $(".advanced_search a").addClass("advancedsearch_icon");
  }
    });
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.advancedsearch_icon{
 background: url('https://image.ibb.co/fxUXFQ/filter.png') no-repeat right 0; width: 20px; height: 20px; padding-left: 20px;
}
.advancedsearch_icon:hover, .advancedsearch_icon_active,
.advancedsearch_icon:active
{
 background: url('https://image.ibb.co/kY4opk/filter_hover.png') no-repeat right 0; width: 20px; height: 20px; padding-left: 20px;
}

.overlay_search {
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 background:#eeeeee;
 overflow:hidden;
 z-index:3;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 24px -8px rgba(18,17,12,0.5); -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 24px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); box-shadow: 7px 7px 24px -8px rgba(18,17,12,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="advanced_search">
  <a class="advancedsearch_icon" href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="overlay_search">
  content is here.
</div>
```